# Python Selenium Webdriver - Javascript .click() integration in python script

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

### I'm struggling to a run Javascript code inside my python selenium script.
The way javascript ".click()" is far more efficient than selenium.
I need to convert this javascript into python, and i'm not familiar with JS :

const MyVariable= $(".modal-test").prev();

```
     } else {
        await MyVariable.each(function (i, el) {
           r = Math.random();
           if (i >= 20 && r > 0.2) {
              $(el).click();
           }
```

Someone could help me ??

Thanks !

EDIT :

Thank you PDHide for your answer ! i'm trying to adapt your advices to my script but no luck for the moment.

Here's a piece of my code :

```
            try: 
                modal = "modal-vote__greeting"
                element = WebDriverWait(driver, 3).until(
                    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, (modal)))
                )
                element.click()
                print("<", end='\r')
                driver.execute_script("""
                    const picForVote = $(".modal-vote__photo__voted").prev();
                        if (picForVote.length === 0) {
                            $('div[ng-click="$ctrl.submit()"]').click();
                            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 4000));
                            $('div[ng-click="$ctrl.close()"]').click();
                            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 4000));
                            continue;

                        } else {
                            await picForVote.each(function (i, el) {
                            r = Math.random();
                            if (i >= 20 && r > 0.2) {
                                $(el).click();
                            }
                            });
                            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 4000));
                            $('div[ng-click="$ctrl.submit()"]').click();
                            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 4000));
                            $('div[ng-click="$ctrl.close()"]').click();
                            await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 4000));
                        }""")
```

Comment: what are you trying to do , the javascript code is not complete

Answer (score 0):

you can execute script in selenium as :

```
driver.execute_script("""

 const MyVariable= $(".modal-test").prev();

 } else {
    await MyVariable.each(function (i, el) {
       r = Math.random();
       if (i >= 20 && r > 0.2) {
          $(el).click();
       }""")
```

if you get $ not defined error then use:

```
driver.execute_script("""var jquery_script = document.createElement('script'); 
jquery_script.src = 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js';
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jquery_script);


     const MyVariable= $(".modal-test").prev();

     } else {
        await MyVariable.each(function (i, el) {
           r = Math.random();
           if (i >= 20 && r > 0.2) {
              $(el).click();
           }""")
```

here we are enabling jquery by adding a script tag

Comment: Thanks for you help PDHide ! i added the piece of my try code condition. For the moment it's not working

Comment: It appears my problem is far more complicated, i figured out that i'm i'm trying to use JS script that requires puppeteer module. Thanks anyway, i will dig it ;)